# Filter the ids of a list of different resources

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

### The Setup

```
mix phx.gen.html Products Fruit fruits name
mix phx.gen.html Products Vegetable vegetables name
```

I have a list `products` of fruits and vegetables:

```
products = []
products = products ++ Products.get_fruits!(1)
products = products ++ Products.get_vegetables!(1)
products = products ++ Products.get_fruits!(2)
```

### The Problem

How can I get the `id`s of all `fruits` and all `vegetables` in that list `products`?

I thought about something like this:

```
vegetable_ids = []
fruit_ids = []

for product <- products do
  case product do
    %Abc.Products.Vegetable{__meta__: _, id: id, inserted_at: _, name: _, updated_at: _} -> vegetable_ids = vegetable_ids ++ [id]
    %Abc.Products.Fruit{__meta__: _, id: id, inserted_at: _, name: _, updated_at: _} -> fruit_ids = fruit_ids ++ [id]
  end
end
```

Is there a better less cumbersome way of filtering all ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use 2 `for` instead, making use of the fact that `for` ignores elements which don't match the pattern instead of raising an error. There's also no need to pattern match the fields you want to ignore.

```
vegetable_ids = for %Abc.Products.Vegetable{id: id} <- products, do: id
fruit_ids = for %Abc.Products.Fruit{id: id} <- products, do: id
```